# What does the mask generation function in PKCS#1 output if the generated mask is shorter than the specified mask length?

Tags: rsa, padding, oaep, pkcs1

I am implementing RSA-OAEP with the mask generation function as specified in PKCS #1. It says after producing the variable T to "output the leading *maskLen* octets of T as the octet string *mask*". However, in one part of RSA-OAEP, where the mask generation function is used on a random seed, maskLen is greater than T. I don't believe I put in the wrong maskLen. RSA-OAEP does not work unless the output of the function is of the specified maskLen. Should I copy T to a byte array of length maskLen?

Answer (score 1):

In MFG1, the size of $T$ in octets of the provisionally generated mask is never smaller than the specified $maskLen$ at the point where we want to

> Output the leading $maskLen$ octets of $T$ as the octet string $mask$.

That follows from the fact that $T$ was built as the concatenation of $\lceil maskLen/hLen\rceil$ hashes, each of $hLen$ octets.

See the algorithm given in [PKCS #1 V2.2, section B.2.1](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=51). Notice that the notation $\lceil maskLen/hLen\rceil$ means that the division is with the rounding upwards. In C and Java, if `maskLen > 0`, that is obtained as `(maskLen - 1)/hLen + 1`. This can not cause overflow, and the final `+ 1` nicely cancels with the prescribed `- 1` in $\lceil maskLen/hLen\rceil-1$.